# opposite of `bind_cols()` in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

It is trivial to bind vectors into a data.frame with `data.frame()`, `tibble()`, or `bind_cols()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- 1:5
y <- letters[1:5]
d <- tibble(x, y)
```

What is the most efficient way to reverse this operation - i.e., take a dataframe and break it into a list with length equal to the `ncol(d)`? In the example above, the desired output would look like this:

```r
> list(x = x, y = y)

$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$y
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

A single function that accomplishes this would be useful, for example, when piping a dataframe to `pmap()`:

```r
d %>%
  break_into_list() %>% # missing function here
  pmap(function(x, y) paste(x, y)) # scales to dataframe with ncol > 2
```

Comment: Do you really need to convert `tibble` in the `list`? Perhaps a better way would be to use `group_map`. This function expects `tibble` as input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `unclass` which also gives an `attribute` for 'row.names'

```
unclass(d)
```

---

Or with `as.list`

```
as.list(d)
```

If the names should be NULL, use `setNames`

```
setNames(as.list(d), NULL)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

---

Regarding the use of `pmap`, we don't need to convert to `list`.  Assuming that we need to loop over the rows (which the `pmap` does)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
d %>% 
    pmap(~ f(..1, ..2))
```

where `..1` and `..2` are the 1st and 2nd columns that are used as input to the function where the `f` will be applied on each row.  If there are more columns and the function requires more inputs, use `..3`, `..4` etc.

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the legendary response time. ;)  This works. I usually do `%>% setNames()` in my pipes and this is familiar. It would be nice to have a way to automatically `setNames`. I'm somewhat surprised that dplyr doesn't have a function to do exactly this. I'm going to check the docs now. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html

Comment: Actually, my example is not the greatest because the colnames are not there. If I specify good column names (which dataframes should have), `as.list()` works quite well. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: @RichPauloo the `..1`  or `..2` in the `pmap` is not related to the column names.  It is just that your column names are similar here i.e. `...1` and `...2` because it was unnamed while creating the tibble